# Group By LINQ Dyanmic Query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to allow the user to change the query dynamically by a querystring parameter.  I am having trouble getting the group by to work in vb.net.  I am wanting to return the id, name, and count of each group.

```
        ' load all of the types

Dim baseQuery = db.Answers _
    .Where(Function(a) a.Question.CorrectAnswer <> a.answer) _
    .Where(Function(a) a.Question.TypeId = TypeId)

If catId <> 0 Then
    baseQuery = baseQuery _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Question.CategoryId = catId) _
        .ToList()
End If

If approachId <> 0 Then
    baseQuery = baseQuery _
        .Where(Function(x) x.ApproachId = approachId) _
        .ToList()
End If

Dim grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal = baseQuery _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Question.TypeId) _
    .Select(Function(x) New With {.id = x.id}) _
    .ToList()

Dim grouppedCategorieincorrectTotal = baseQuery _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Question.CategoryId) _
    .ToList()

Dim grouppedApproachesincorrectTotal = baseQuery _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.ApproachId) _
    .ToList()

ViewBag.QuestionTypes = grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal
ViewBag.Categories = grouppedCategorieincorrectTotal
ViewBag.Approaches = grouppedApproachesincorrectTotal
```

Comment: To start with, try removing most of the `ToList()` calls. Only put a `ToList` just before the assignments to the `ViewBag`.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I still can't figure out how to return the count & name.

'
            Dim grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal = baseQuery.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {.Id = x.Id}).ToList
            ViewBag.QuestionTypes = grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal'

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to return "Name". Nowhere in your sample code is a "Name" property.

Comment: Sorry, name is abstract in the view.  Example Name = Category.Name,   Name = Approach.Name.

Everything appears to be returning fine, except "name" now -- 

            Dim grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal = baseQuery.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {.Id = x.Question.TypeId}).Select(Function(x) New With {x.Key, x.Count})
            ViewBag.QuestionTypes = grouppedQuestionTypesincorrectTotal